# Are there JavaScript template engines that work in Adobe Air apps?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, air

I'm trying to build an Adobe Air app not using Flash but HTML5. I hit a snag when trying to use templates since most of them like handlebars and underscore's templates rely on `eval` or `new Function(...)` or `Function.apply(...)` and Adobe Air has restricted runtime use of `eval` to parsing only JSON objects.

Does anyone know of a js templating engine that will work on Air apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templating libraries that do not use `eval` or `Function`

- [plates](https://github.com/flatiron/plates)

Comment: I had to adjust the code because Adobe Air can't handle reserved words as property names yet and it was dying on the `class` method but otherwise works well enough now. Thanks.

Comment: @OriginalSyn for future reference just make a [pull request](https://github.com/flatiron/plates/pull/53) ;)

Comment: I was intending to but I'm on my Windows machine right now and have some issues with github and my ssh keys I haven't got around to fixing yet. Thanks for taking care of it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another templating engine that doesn't use `eval` or `Function`:

- [Distal](http://code.google.com/p/distal)

Answer (score 0):

Another famous template engine compatibe to Adobe AIR and my favorite choice: markup.js from Adam Mark. I like it, because the Syntax is like Handelbar.js or Template7.js. Clear and intuitive!

- https://github.com/adammark/Markup.js